# What is the output of the following javascript code and why?

Tags: javascript, function

I am really new in JavaScript. Can you please explain what should be the output of the following JavaScript Code? Please explain the reason as detail as possible. Thank you so much.

```
var Foo = function( a ) { 
    function bar() {   
        return a; 
    }
    this.baz = function() {   
        return a; 
    };
};

Foo.prototype = {
    biz: function() {    
        return a; 
    }        
};

var f = new Foo( 7 );
f.bar(); 
f.baz(); 
f.biz();
```

Comment: The result is an error. f.bar is not a function. That is because it is a local function with scope only within the Foo function. `baz` is available since it is part of the constructed object when you do `new Foo()`.  `f.biz()` is also available since it is placed in Foo's prototype meaning it is shared by all instances of Foo (f being one of them).

Comment: As a continuation to what @rasmeister said: `f.baz` return the value of `a` (`7`) but `foo.biz` return `undefined` because `a` is not defined withing that scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is an error. f.bar is not a function. That is because it is a local function with scope only within the Foo function. It is effectively a private function only available within the function it is defined in.

When you call new Foo(), you are invoking the function as a constructor. This will create an object and return it. Within the function that object can be referenced as 'this'. Since `baz` is added as a property to the `this` object, it will be included in the object created when you do `f = new Foo(7)`.

baz is available since it is part of the constructed object when you do new Foo().

f.biz() is also available since it is placed in Foo's prototype. Adding a prototype meaning it is shared by all instances of Foo (f being one of them).

The variable a is only defined within the constructor function, so it will be undefined in the biz() function call. Consequently, f.biz() will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Not only will this throw an error since f.bar() is only accessible *inside* the Foo function scope (eg its basically a "private" method), but also all of the methods (bar, baz, biz) reference the property "a" which isnt actually defined as a property of Foo instances.

You should be storing "a" inside Foo using `this.a = a`, and accessing it inside your Foo methods (bar, baz, biz) using `return this.a`

Answer (score 0):

you can do as below.

```js
var Foo = function( a ) { 
  this.a = a;
    this.bar = function() {   
        return this.a; 
    }
    this.baz = function() {   
        return this.a; 
    };
};

Foo.prototype = {
    biz: function() {    
        return this.a; 
    }        
};

var f = new Foo( 7 );
console.log(f.bar()); 
console.log(f.baz()); 
console.log(f.biz());
```